# C - Loop through void* knowing element size

Tags: c, arrays, void-pointers

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct genericArray
{
    void* elements;
    size_t element_size;
    size_t num_of_elemtns;
} *GenericArray;
```

And the following function:

```
void MyFunction(GenericArray array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array->num_of_elemtns; i++)
    {
        void* element =  array->elements + array->element_size * i;
    }
}
```

I want to itarete for each element in when the size of each element in the array is known.
However, I get a compilation error: `Error  2   error C2036: 'void *' : unknown size`.
Is it possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot perform pointer arithmetic using `void*`, it needs to be at least a `char*`

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks, the problem is that the type of the elements in the array is unknown

Comment: You can refer to elements of any type using `char*` - the standard guarantees it to be allowed

Comment: if you cast it to `char *`, it means to look at data pointer as a pointer  to 1 byte data size. so you can access it like this: `void* element =  (char*)(array->elements) + array->element_size * i;`

Comment: the posted code defines a pointer via a typedef.  This is (almost) always a bad idea